# How to solve implicit differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we go from the equation and go backwards:
$$y=c\,e^x+e^{2x+c}$$where $c$ is any arbitrary constant.
Now,
$$y'=c\times(e^x)+(2e^c)\times(e^{2x}).$$ Solving for $c$: we get $$c=\ln\left(\frac{y'-y}{e^{2x}}\right).$$

Putting the value of $c$ in original equation we get the differential equation as:$$2y=\ln\left(\frac{y'-y}{e^{2x}}\right)\times(e^x)+y'$$

Now, can we solve this implicitly defined differential equation although its order may be $1$?

Comment: it's e^(2x) to avoid confusion

Comment: so, its not an ODE? then how to reach at the solution ?

Comment: No, it is not a DAE, it is an implicit ODE. For a DAE you would need a system, i.e., at least two dependent variables, one differential and one algebraic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the ODE leads to the expected function $y(x)$ if we look only for real solutions. But they are extra solutions in the complex domain :

[image]

Comment: will substitution always work if more implicit functions are present such as sinusoidal along with logarithms & exponential?

Comment: Certainly not. it works only in favourable cases and if a convenient subsitution is found.