# forming ODE by elimination of arbitrary constant

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let

$$y= \sin (a)e^{2x}+e^{a+3x}+\ln(a)e^x$$

If we differentiate , we get $y'$. Now, since the number of arbitrary constant is 1, we can expect the differential equation to be of order=1.But we are not able to eliminate '$a$' from the two equations given by $y=f(x)$ & $y'=f(x,y)$. We cannot use $y''$ since it will yield an order 2 ODE which will be incorrect .So, how can we get the 1st order ODE?

Also, assuming we get the first order ODE can we work backwards to solve it ? I think we can but the implicit nature of the ODE may not permit substitution to work very well. So, how can we solve it?

Comment: @Moo: No. 'a' is any arbitrary constant.Not necessarily 1.

Comment: @Moo: How do you eliminate 'a' in the equation for y' ? 'a' is present in implicit form as sin and ln . Is it possible just from 2 equations (1 from given y and another from y')?

Comment: @Moo: I apologise for my description of the question if it does not seem very clear.My motivation is to achieve the required ODE that the given equation will yield and as far as I know it can be achieved by eliminating the arbitrary constant.As a secondary target , if successful in obtaining the ODE is to try to reach the question which will be the solution of the ODE. Please ,can you suggest a procedure to get the ODE

Comment: Please refer to a similar question that was solved here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695805/how-to-solve-implicit-differential-equation